# Data Passing from Custom Table View Controller to a View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have made a custom table view controller in which there are some labels which are taking values from an API response. Some of the values are shown in custom table view , i have another view controller called Detail vc , in which i want to show the detail of the data i'm getting from API. I'm passing the data from custom table to detail vc through segue but i'm facing an error, i don't know where is the problem coming . I had used the same method to pass data from one vc to another vc there it was working fine, but i don't know why it is not working here. The error is,

> 2017-07-11 15:57:22.177 PK.House[9403:604414] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[StringData length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800012b400'

My code for segue is,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]) {
        //Do something
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ShowViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
         destViewController.tites = [_Title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.prce = [_Price objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.ara = [_LandArea objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.phon = [_Phone objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // destViewController.citi = [_City objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.loc = [_location objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // destViewController.tye = [_type objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // destViewController.Idss = [_Id objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.nam = [_name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.emal = [_email objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.roomss = [_rooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.wash = [_washroom objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.flloors = [_floor objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         //destViewController.stat = [_status objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.descrp = [_descrip objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // destViewController.countryy = [_country objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
}
```

Detail vc is,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"BACK"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(backBtnClicked)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
    backButton.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

   /* int x=0;
    NSArray *image=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"city.png",@"area.png",@"twitter.png", nil];
    for (int i=0; i<image.count; i++)
    {
        UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
        img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[image objectAtIndex:i]];
        x=x+[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;

    }*/

    self.Title.text = _tites;
    self.name.text = _nam;
    self.email.text = _emal;
    self.status.text = _stat;
    self.type.text = _tye;
    self.phone.text = _phon;
    self.rooms.text = _roomss;
    self.floor.text = _flloors;
    self.washroom.text = _wash;
    self.location.text = _loc;
    self.Descrip.text = _descrp;
    self.city.text = _citi;
    self.country.text = _countryy;
    self.propid.text = Idss;


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: There may be issues with datatypes.. Check your declared datatypes again...

Comment: Where are you using StringData ?

Comment: if u give me ur email i can explain u totally there in detail. @AravindAR

Comment: In objective-c, a selector is a method on a class or instance of a class. The error you are receiving means that something you are doing is calling `length` on an instance of `StringData`, and `StringData` doesn't have that selector (aka method). You should set an [all exceptions breakpoint](https://www.natashatherobot.com/xcode-debugging-user-breakpoints/) in the debugger to see exactly where your code is failing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of the data that you're using the `objectAtIndex` method on is just a string instead of an array. Probably it's one or all of these: `_Title`, `_Price`, `_name`, etc.

Comment: i have made seperate array for each. @halil_g

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
self.Title.text = _tites;
self.name.text = _nam;
self.email.text = _emal;
self.status.text = _stat;
self.type.text = _tye;
self.phone.text = _phon;
self.rooms.text = _roomss;
self.floor.text = _flloors;
self.washroom.text = _wash;
self.location.text = _loc;
self.Descrip.text = _descrp;
self.city.text = _citi;
self.country.text = _countryy;
self.propid.text = Idss;
```

one of the variables you're assigning to `.text` is an NSArray.

Double check that the values you get after calling `objectAtIndex:` are actually strings. My guess is that one of them is an array.

Comment: let me check it